# Position percentage to degree

Tags: c++, math, geometry

```
double x = ...;        // -1.0 to 1.0
double y = ...;        // -1.0 to 1.0
int deg = (int) ((atan(x / y) * 57.2958) + (y > 0 ? 540 : 360)) % 360;
```

Some basic geometry that I can't seem to figure out right now. Spent a while on it. Above code works ok-ish but seems to be mirrored wrong and I'm pretty sure a mod isn't required here.

I have aa rather odd scenario, I need those degree outputs when the red dot is at that position. Basically a mirrored unit circle.

[image]

Looking for an easy implementation (and maybe a geometry refresher).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need:

```
degrees = atan2(x, y) * 360.0 / (2.0 * M_PI) + 180.0;
```

Note the use of [atan2](http://linux.die.net/man/3/atan2) to get a valid 4 quadrant result. We also need to add π radians (180 degrees) since `atan2` returns values in the range -π to π.

Note also that x and y are transposed compared to the more conventional usage (`atan2(y, x)`).

[<kbd>LIVE DEMO</kbd>](http://ideone.com/MJk87o)